# How to identify if sql server 2005 express is installed using cmd

Tags: sql-server, cmd

How to identify if sql server 2005 express is installed using cmd

Comment: I was looking froward to know if sql-server express is installed or not... if no i would fire the exe to install it... all this within a .bat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a dirty hack, you can check whether sqlcmd command can be executed.

EDIT

yep, I was right.

> To determine if you have MSDE or
>   Microsoft SQL Server installed on your
>   computer:
>
> 1. On the taskbar at the bottom of your screen, click Start, and then
>      click Search.
> 2. In the Search dialog box, type sqlservr.exe
> 3. Click OK.
>
>    If this file is present on your system, then you have MSDE or SQL
>      Server installed.

http://www.microsoft.com/security/updates/checkversion.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is not using a comman or sqlcmd but this will get you the version of the named server

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=true;initial catalog=master"))
{
    connection.Open();
    string version = connection.ServerVersion;
}
```